# What is CPU burst?

Tags: amazon-ec2, central-processing-unit

Amazon has recently [announced](http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2010/09/09/announcing-micro-instances-for-amazon-ec2/) Micro instances for Amazon EC2. I'm also keep reading about "... allow you to ***burst CPU capacity*** when additional cycles are available."

My question is, what does CPU burst mean?  I want to know/understand this better.

Any pointers, articles, documentation, etc. on the same are appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Good question - meanwhile there is more information available regarding this topic:

- Amazon has added a still pretty high level FAQ, see [How does a Micro instance compare in compute power to a Standard Small instance?](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/faqs/#How_does_a_Micro_instance_compare)

  > At steady state, Micro instances receive a fraction of the compute resources that Small instances do. Therefore, if your application has
  >   compute-intensive or steady state needs we recommend using a Small
  >   instance (or larger, depending on your needs). However, Micro
  >   instances can periodically burst up to 2 ECUs (for short periods of
  >   time). This is double the number of ECUs available from a Standard
  >   Small instance. Therefore, if you have a relatively low throughput
  >   application or web site with an occasional need to consume significant
  >   compute cycles, we recommend using Micro instances.
  >
  > *[Note: ECU is a “EC2 Compute Unit”, see [What is a “EC2 Compute Unit” and why did you introduce it?](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/faqs/#What_is_an_EC2_Compute_Unit_and_why_did_you_introduce_it) for details]*
- The Amazon EC2 User Guide has gained a dedicated, elaborate and especially **illustrated chapter** on [Micro Instances](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/concepts_micro_instances.html) as well, it is a highly recommended read for everybody thinking about using this interesting instance type!
- Finally, [Amazon EC2 Micro Instance and Stolen CPU](http://gregsramblings.com/2011/02/07/amazon-ec2-micro-instance-cpu-steal/) offers an interesting analysis and demonstration how the throttling works, as observed on a micro instance running Ubuntu Linux.

Answer (score 1):

In a nutshell, if the host is not experiencing CPU contention, you'll be able to use more CPU "shares" (for short periods of time) than are normally reserved for your EC2 instance.

Comment: Any long answer/article on this topic?

Comment: Honestly, there's not much more to know about it other than what I posted. I'm sure you could get into the inticracies of the Xen CPU scheduler if you wanted to, but I don't have access to that information nor time to research it now. From a user's perspective, all you really need to know is what I initially posted.